# How to get group in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have my build.gradle like this:

```
group = "com.example"
...
task example {
    println group
}
```

It is throwing an error.

It is a simple build.gradle file with dependencies etc. It does everything fine. I just don't know how to print group. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you try `println project.group`? Also would be worth mentioning the applied plugins in your `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of getting the project `group` from within a task is like so:

```
task example {
    println project.group
}
```